# How do I build an EF Interceptor with a list of values

Tags: entity-framework

I'm trying to develop an Entity Framework interceptor to filter the information for a tenant. The information is customers, and each customer is in a group, and each user can see a number of groups.

So, I'm trying to develop the interceptor with a Visitor to include a DbExpression that will check if the user is in a number of groups.

I presume I need to create one with something like DbExpressionBuilder.In or something like that. Does anyone have an example of how to do this? I have plenty of examples of using say, an integer, but not a list of values.

Comment: May be [Dynamic Global Filters](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework.DynamicFilters) will help you.

Comment: @Tim Almond did you ever find a solution?  What you're describing is precisely what I'm up against.